# how to make windows xp always arrange folders by date

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I frequently access some folders and look at the latest file in that folder. Sometimes, I also need to attach the latest file in email and send. Windows seems to always sort the folder by name. I have to then make it sort again on date and then carry on the operation. I didn't find anything in the windows explorer or the File open dialog box that will allow me to make sorting by date permanent.

Similar functionality is needed in Windows 7 machine also.
Suggestions appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've set up a folder to your liking, go to Tools, Folder Options, the View tab, and click "Apply to All Folders". This will make it the default layout throughout Explorer.

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I wonder why this was not apparent to me. I am still struggling on how to ensure that when I do the file open, the folder is listed with all details. Right now it presents just the file name. When I click on the details, then it shows the list in sorted order. However, I *still* have to click on details. Inputs appreciated